# Null pointer exception at method RecyclerView.setLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

Im facing issues with RecyclerViewAdapter

Following is my error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(andr‌​oid.support.v7.widge‌​t.RecyclerView$Layou‌​tManager)'

on line :

> recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

I set adapter recyclerview when fragment is create and when user click an item in recyclerview , it calls api to update this recyclerview but problem is when user click item above exception occurs

How to fix it

Following is my code :

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) lay_custom_center_post_topic.findViewById(R.id.lv_poll_feed);

 AdapDetailTopicPoll adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(timelineFeedListModels.get(i).getPost().getPoll());
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
adapDetailTopicPoll.notifyDataSetChanged();

new_position = i;
```

---

```
 public void sendVodePoll(final int position, String poll_id,final int new_position, final List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> poll) {

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String URL = "xxxx/xx";
        params.put("poll_id", poll_id);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> pollBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean>();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String vote = null;
                String poll_id=null;
                String status_vote=null;
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                try {
                    List<TopicVoteModel> topicVoteModels = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0 ; i<response.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        vote = jsonObject.getString("vote");
                        topicVoteModels.add(gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), TopicVoteModel.class));
                    }

                    boolean new_status_vote = Boolean.parseBoolean(status_vote);

                    poll.get(position).setVote(Integer.parseInt(vote));
                    poll.get(position).setStatus_vote(new_status_vote);

                    for (ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean pollBean : poll){
                        pollBeanArrayList.add(pollBean);
                    }

                    adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(pollBeanArrayList, context);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager); //inline this error
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
                    adapDetailTopicPoll.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

adapter

```
public class AdapDetailTopicPoll extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapDetailTopicPoll.MyViewHolder> {

    SearchDetailFragment searchDetailFragment = new SearchDetailFragment();
    Context context;
    private List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> poll = new ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean>();

    public AdapDetailTopicPoll( List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> poll ,Context context){
        this.poll = poll;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_profile_feed_topic_poll,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tx_poll.setText(""+poll.get(position).getName());
        if (poll.get(position).isStatus_vote()==false){
            holder.img_vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.vote_t_1);
            holder.tx_count_vote.setText(""+poll.get(position).getVote());

        }else {
            holder.img_vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.vote_t_2);
            holder.tx_count_vote.setText(""+poll.get(position).getVote());

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return poll.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tx_poll,tx_count_vote;
        public ImageView img_vote;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tx_poll = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_poll);
            tx_count_vote = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_count_vote);
            img_vote = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_vote);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ProfileFragment.poll_id = String.valueOf(poll.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    searchDetailFragment.sendVodePoll(getAdapterPosition(),ProfileFragment.poll_id,SearchDetailFragment.new_position,poll);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide full code of your fragment

Comment: Post your logcat and fragment

Comment: please show us where you have initialized recyclerView object?

Comment: In which method you are finding reference of recycle view?

Comment: Make sure you have initialized recycler view

Comment: You fix it by using `findViewById` correctly

Comment: @NileshRathod i edited post ,please check for me

Comment: Please create a [mcve], which means "minimal" only *up-to* the error, really. `lay_custom_center_post_topic` is now undefined... Please show how you created that

Comment: Generally speaking `+@id/lv_poll_feed` is not in the layout file you are trying to find it in

Comment: @cricket_007 lay_custom_center_post_topic is my relativelayout (store lb_poll_feed)

Comment: Please stop adding all the other **unrelated** code that is after the error. Add the code that happens **before** this stuff currently displayed

Comment: @cricket_007 this line is not error! , my problem is in method `sendVodePoll`

Comment: @cricket_007 I can set adapterrecyclerview in first time is work! but when i click item in recyclerview is not work

Comment: @cricket_007 i edited and comment this line error please check for me

Comment: Seriously? Your logcat says the NullPointerException before the adapter is ever created. Please stop adding that code

Comment: @cricket_007 please move to discussion to chat with me

Comment: @cricket_007 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150248/discussion-between-arr-s-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Write these lines directly in onCreate() method of the activity

```
adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(pollBeanArrayList, context);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
```

and initialize the adapter and arraylist as the global variable.

Answer (score -2):

In RecyclerView there are 2 ways that are commonly used - In the form of a List or in the form of a Grid. So for list formation you'll provide a layout manager like this -

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerFuture = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManagerFuture.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

and for Grid formation

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, totalItemsInOneRow);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: How does this help if the RecyclerView is null?

Comment: Null pointer is at invoking the `andr‌​oid.support.v7.widge‌​t.RecyclerView$Layou‌​tManager` and if the RecyclerView is null then check your declaration for the recycler view, confirm the ids, make sure you have the required libraries.

Comment: No... `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager` was attempted on a null object reference, so that means the View is null.